doubling up a variable 0-5V DC voltage and still being able to draw at least 100mA
I need to multiply by 2 a variable 0-5V DC voltage that has very low current capability and still be able to draw at least 100mA. So a classic opamp like TL072 is not suitable.
I've got at my disposal a small range of classic IC (opamp, 555, OTA etc) and passive components. I can power the circuit up to +-15V and a lot of current. I'm only able to use through-hole 8-DIP components.
Any ideas?

What do you mean by "double up"?

doubling means multiplying by 2. Corrected to avoid confusion.

Touche. Do you want to multiply the voltage or multiply the circuit?

I don't get your comment. My question is clear. I want to multiply (double) the voltage. Any tips? Thank you

Is 0-5V source the only source you have? What's its maximum output current? Can it source at least 200-300 mA?

That's the source I want to amplify. It has very low current capability. For info it's a CV source from a Midi2CV interface.

Some opamps can provide more than 100mA, like the LM7332. Or a power amplifier. Or you could use any opamp to drive a voltage regulator or buck converter, provided that you have a power source double than 5V that can source that.

@Rohat Kılıç, If I misunderstood you question, I can of course power the circuit up to +-15V

@Gos, Thank you. I'm trying to achieve this with the component I have. Also I will correct my question to point out that I'm using 8-DIP ICs

I can power the circuit up to +-15V and a lot of current. OK, now your question is clearer because if the 0-5V source was the only source  then users here might suggest a boost regulator which would draw 2x the output current from the source (for 100% efficiency). Anyway, since you are limited to using DIP8 ICs, I'd suggest high-power op amps such as the one Gos mentioned. If you have any chance to use BJTs then a non-inv amplifier with 2x gain and a push-pull stage would work (both supplied from your ±15 source).

This is a class assignment? You have BJTs available?

@SpehroPefhany No it's not. I'm 52. But thanks for the BJT tip.

OK, so:
0-5V input ; 0-10V output (gain 2) ; Output current 100mA ; Supply +/- 15V.
For a high-ish output current like 100mA, it's important to check power dissipation. The output transistor in the opamp or other gain stage will conduct the output current, and it will drop a voltage equal to the difference between its supply voltage and output voltage. Dissipated power is the product of the two.
If the load draws constant current, maximum dissipated power in the opamp will occur at Vout=0V, ie 15V x 0.1A = 1.5W.
If the load is resistive, say 100 ohms, then output current depends on voltage. In this case maximum power is 0.56W at Vout=7.4V.
With the simple opamp plus transistor circuit you described in the comments:

Problem: MPSA18 is a small TO92 transistor which is limited to a maximum dissipation of 625mW at 25°C ambient, so if the output delivers 100mA it will run very hot, and burn out in case the output is shorted.
A simple solution would be to stick a heat sink on the TO92, which will be okay for 0.6W but not much more, as it is a plastic transistor which is unable to conduct much heat. Or simply use a more heat sink friendly transistor in TO220 package.
Here's a short circuit protection: if output current rises above Vbe(Q3)/R4 or about 120mA, Q3 turns on and steals base current from Q1, which limits the output current to 120mA. The opamp will try to make Q1 conduct and raise its positive output as much as it can, so R1 should not be too low.

Note TL072 needs a negative supply here, because its inputs cannot operate near its negative supply. If you use an opamp which still works with its inputs near the negative supply like LM358, then you don't need a negative supply.

I finally managed by just adding a MPSA18 transistor with its base connected to the output of a TL072 configured to double the input voltage. This could allow the circuit to draw 90mA.
Thank you.

Good +1, but be careful of the power dissipation. The TO-92 is only good for a a few hundred mW. A TIP41 or something of that ilk would be better if you need high current at low output voltage (so lots of volts across the transistor and therefore high power dissipation). 100mA at ~0V out and +15 supply would be 1.5W which requires a heat sink even for a TO-220.

Look at charge pump doublers, they are switched capacitor circuits that essentially take two caps in parallel, charge them to Vcc and then put them in series to double the voltage.
This one is an example and it does 100mA:

https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/cat661-d.pdf
Which could be used with an 8 soic to 8 dip converter:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/aries-electronics/LCQT-SOIC8-8/4754588
OR the LT1054

Source: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1054-1054L.pdf

doesn't work if the to be doubled voltage has only low current capability ( it is only a signal essentially afaiu)

Only DIP? are you sure? haven't seen those around for a while :D
anyway, yes it can be done. Two stage solution. First use opamp (whichever), and set it to gain of 2. then use n-channel mos. You can implement a feedback, measuring the voltage over load and bring it back to Vin- of the opamp. If it sounds to complicated it probably is for your level of knowledge and i would suggest against implementing such circuit because it will be pain to debug without 100% understanding of what's going on.
You can use high-current output opamps. I think L2720 would do the job, but it is obsolete for some years.
Maybe look into TLE2301, it is also quite old. I think it fits your needs. 1A output current, +/- power supply. Just use it as non-inverting op-amp with gain of 2 and that's it.
